# How to call another script in Office scripts?

Tags: office-scripts

Is there anyway to call another script in office scripts?
Have been attempting to call other functions into my main function in a single script and while it is indeed calling the function, for some reason the entriety of the function wont execute, so I wanted to try calling another script

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OfficeScripts does not currently have a facility for calling functions in other script files. If that's something that you think would be super interesting for you, you can request it as a feature on User Voice using the link here - https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/274580-excel-for-the-web?category_id=143439

-Jim

Answer (score 4):

Use Power Automate (Flow) to call other Office Scripts one after each other! You can pass parameters between them, also.
[Power Automate connects scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSeDH.png)